# Bash how to append word to end of a line?

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk, grep

I have executed a command in bash to retrieve some addresses from a file like this:

```
grep address file.txt | cut -d'=' -f2 | tr ':' ' '
```

yields:

```
xxx.xx.xx.xxx port1
xxx.xx.xx.xxx port2
```

and I would like to append ' eth0' to each of those output lines and then ideally for loop over the result to call a command with each line. Problem I'm having is getting that extra string in the end to each line. I tried:

```
| sed -e 's/\(.+)\n/\1 eth0/g'
```

which didn't work..and then supposing I got it there, if I wrap it in a for loop it won't pass in the full lines since they contain spaces. So how do I go about this?

Comment: what does the input file look like?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can match `$` to append to a line, like:

```
sed -e 's/$/ eth0/'
```

EDIT:

To loop over the lines, I'd suggest using a `while` loop, like:

```
while read line
do
  # Do your thing with $line
done < <(grep address file.txt | cut -d'=' -f2 | tr ':' ' ' | sed -e 's/$/ eth0')
```

Comment: Cool, and how do I loop over the results in the end? The spacing causes me to loop over each word and not each line!

Comment: `Bash`, `grep`, `cut`, `tr` and `sed` no no no... What you want can be achieved with either `sed` or `awk` alone.

Comment: @sudo_O While I share your sentiment to an extent, this really isn't that bad :P.  It's in the unix bloodline to chain together a ton of small utilities like that, that's why they exist.

Comment: That's awesome, I always forget the `<(` stuff and was doing `$(`

Comment: @FatalError UNIX is not about chaining together a ton of small utilities when one small utility will do the job.

Answer (score 8):

How about just using `awk`:

```
awk -F= '/address/{gsub(/:/," ");print $2,"eth0"}' file
```

Demo:

```
$ cat file
junk line
address=192.168.0.12:80
address=127.0.0.1:25
don not match this line

$ awk -F= '/address/{gsub(/:/," ");print $2,"eth0"}' file
192.168.0.12 80 eth0
127.0.0.1 25 eth0
```

Or just with `sed`:

```
$ sed -n '/address/{s/:/ /g;s/.*=//;s/$/ eth0/p}' file
192.168.0.12 80 eth0
127.0.0.1 80 eth0
```

Answer (score 4):

I came here looking for the same answer, but none of the above do it as clean as

```
sed -i 's/address=.*/& eth0/g' file
```

Search and replace inline with sed for lines begining with address, replace with the same line plus 'eth0'

eg.

```
sed -i 's/address=.*/& eth0/g' file; cat file
junk line
address=192.168.0.12:80 eth0
address=127.0.0.1:25 eth0
don not match this line
```

Comment: I see that this doesn't call anything per line as indicated, but this answers the title question.

Comment: what does & do here?

Comment: it's basically shorthand for everything from the LHS into the replacement RHS. take another look at the example or try it for yourself.  =)   It's great for pre/post pending.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is:

```
awk -F'[=:]' '{print $2, $3, "eth0"}' file.txt |
while IFS= read -r ip port eth
do
   printf "ip=%s, port=%s, eth=%s\n" "$ip" "$port" "$eth"
done
```

Always use IFS= and -r when using read unless you have a very specific reason not to. google for why.

Answer (score 0):

```
typeset TMP_FILE=$( mktemp )
touch "${TMP_FILE}"
cp -p filename "${TMP_FILE}"
sed -e 's/$/stringToAdd/' "${TMP_FILE}" > filename
```

Answer (score -1):

is this ok for you?

```
kent$ echo "xxx.xx.xx.xxx port1
xxx.xx.xx.xxx port2"|sed 's/.*/& eth0/'
xxx.xx.xx.xxx port1 eth0
xxx.xx.xx.xxx port2 eth0
```

P.S you could merge your cut, tr (even grep in your example) into one sed/awk call, to make the cmdline simpler and faster.